# Wrong tiles in Flutter Flame map

Tags: flutter, tiled, flame

In my Flutter Flame project I have problem with the map.

For showing the problem I have created a simple tileset with two tiles:

[image: tileset]

And a simple map with 3 rows and 4 columns.
In Tiled it looks correct

[image: tiled]

But in the app it looks like that

[image]

This is my map file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.10" tiledversion="1.10.1" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="4" height="3" tilewidth="40" tileheight="40" infinite="0" nextlayerid="2" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tileset" tilewidth="40" tileheight="40" tilecount="2" columns="2">
  <image source="tileset.png" width="80" height="40"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer id="1" name="Tile Layer 1" width="4" height="3">
  <data encoding="csv">
1,1,1,1,
1,2,2,1,
1,1,1,1
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

And in the app I am just doing that:

```
@override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final tiledComponent = await TiledComponent.load("map.tmx", Vector2.all(40));
    add(tiledComponent);
  }
```

Why is it looking different in the app?

I am using Flutter 3.10.0 (stable) and Dart 3.0.0.
And I have seen that the official tile example looks also wrong when I run it:
https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/main/packages/flame_tiled/example

Comment: I downgraded my flutter version to 3.7.12 and it worked as expected. Might be a problem with the newest flutter version.

Comment: That's very curious, I wonder if it is due to some sprite batching bug on Flutter's side.
Could you report this as an issue on our GitHub?
https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues
Also, does this happen on all platforms?

Comment: I tested it only on iOS. I changed back to 3.10.0 and the problem came back.

Comment: I have created an issue @GitHub

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else come across this, it's a regression in impeller (it works fine on the other platforms).

To disable impeller you can do:

```
flutter run --no-enable-impeller
```

or in the `Info.plist` file:

```
  <key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
  <false />
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/impeller#ios) about disabling impeller.